# VB.net - code execution order?

Tags: vb.net, order-of-execution

I've got a simple GUI and I'm simply storing system information and displaying the results.

The two problem areas are the `detectADUC` and `detectExchange` Sub's. The only time the appropriate label will update is when I place one above the order in the form_load event.

I'm thinking maybe that there's something I need to release? Am I holding a value somewhere? Please take a look below.

**detectExchange**

```
Private Sub detectExchange()

    Dim exchange As New ServiceController("Microsoft Exchange Service Host")

    Try
        If exchange.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) Or exchange.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) Then
            Label9.Text = "Detected - Running"
        End If
    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
        Label9.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Label9.Text = "NOT INSTALLED"

    End Try

    If exchange.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) Or exchange.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending) Then
        Label9.Text = "Detected - NOT RUNNING"
    End If

End Sub
```

**detectADUC**

```
Private Sub detectADUC()
    Dim aduc As New ServiceController("Active Directory Domain Services")
    Try
        If aduc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) Or aduc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) Then
            Label10.Text = "Detected - Running"
        End If
    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
        Label10.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Label10.Text = "NOT INSTALLED"

    End Try

    If aduc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) Or aduc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending) Then
        Label10.Text = "Detected - NOT RUNNING"
    End If

End Sub
```

**Calling the subs**

```
Private Sub systemchecks_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RichTextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & (": installation launched")
    Label12.Text = getExternalIP()
    getHostname()
    hardwareID()
    detectOS()
    detectADUC()
    detectExchange()
    hardwareID()
End Sub
```

As you can see the only different is the variable name, service name and the label's it updates. - However only one label will ever update, depending on which one I call first within form_load.

I've tried using `Me.Refresh`, - I've tried adding a new class then creating a public shared sub and then referencing that in form_load.

I even renamed the exchange exception catch to `ex2`

Can someone explain the problem so I can understand and avoid future problems?

Comment: Isnt both the label will have the text _Detected - NOT RUNNING_ even if they are running?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. The label does work correctly.

Comment: Look at the last If statement. The last assignment is `Label10.Text = "Detected - NOT RUNNING"` while it shouldn't be there, I think. OR better yet, remove that IF statement entirely since you already have a try..catch beforehand

Comment: No mater what the try catch statement does your last If-Then will always set the lable to say Detected - NOT RUNNING

Comment: Oh yeh, I've removed that I see what you mean, however that's made no difference to my problem...

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the subs

Comment: Just fixed my code and added how I'm calling the subs.

Comment: No. Remove the entire if statement. *The last one

Comment: No, I need that if statement because it checks if the service is there but if it's stopped or has been marked to be stopped.

Comment: As I already said, you have done that checking in the try..catch. No need for further validation

Comment: That checking is if the service doesn't exist, not if it's been stopped.

Comment: Btw, what is the text being displayed by the labels now after running this?

Comment: The services don't exists on my PC so which ever one I load first properly displays "NOT INSTALLED" but the one I loaded second remains unchanged. <- That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolved this myself,  see below.

```
Private Sub detectExchange()

    Dim exchange As New ServiceController("Microsoft Exchange Service Host")

    Try
        If exchange.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) Or exchange.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) Then
            Label9.Text = "Detected - Running"

        Else

        End If
        If exchange.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) Or exchange.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending) Then
            Label9.Text = "Detected - NOT RUNNING"
        End If

    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
        Label9.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Label9.Text = "NOT INSTALLED"

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub detectADUC()
    Dim aduc As New ServiceController("Active Directory Domain Services")
    Try
        If aduc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) Or aduc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) Then
            Label10.Text = "Detected - Running"

        Else

        End If
        If aduc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) Or aduc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending) Then
            Label10.Text = "Detected - NOT RUNNING"
        End If

    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
        Label10.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Label10.Text = "NOT INSTALLED"

    End Try
End Sub
```